# How can we calculate $(\log_{x}{x})'$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534820/how-can-we-calculate-xx), I am looking for a solution for:

## $(\log_{x}{x})'$ = ?

...where $x$ is **not** 1, but positive.

Comment: $$\log_bb=1$$ if $b>0,\ne1$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Oh, so simple and clean. Post an answer! :-)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Asked this answer my math teacher, and he didn't know to answer... ^_^

Comment: @Johnツ, if that's true then change of teacher...or of school.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Mistakes happen sometimes. Have you never a dumb moment?

Comment: I can't believe I stared at this for five minutes before seeing what was going on!  I actually tried $y = \log_x x \Rightarrow x^y = x \Rightarrow y \ln x  = \ln x \Rightarrow y = 1$ before I figured it out!  Question of Great Good Humor! ;-)

Comment: Oh, yes I have, @nik ! But like this one and from a teacher? Hmmm...even if (s)he didn't notice immediately that $\;\log_xx=1\;$ , she could have readily tried change of basis: $$\log_xx=\frac{\log_e x}{\log_e x}=1$$ That (s)he didn't come up with the answer makes me wonder...

Comment: @DonAntonio Maybe an answer would be that I asked this question after I asked [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534820/how-can-we-calculate-xx) one. I have a good math teacher. (S)he was so happy to find the answer today. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that $\log_x x=1.$ Is that enough?

Comment: Remember: $\log_b a$ is the number we raise $b$ to to get $a.$ In other words, $\log_b a= c$ if and only if $b^c=a.$

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it the hard way, let $f(y,z) = \log_y z = \frac{\ln z}{\ln y}$, so that your function is $g(x) = f(x,x)$. 
It is easy to compute that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(y,z) = \frac{1}{z \ln y}.$ It is almost as easy to compute that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(y,z) = \frac{1}{y} \cdot \frac{-\ln z}{\ln^2 y}$.

You have:
$$ g'(x) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,x) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(x,x).$$
When you substitute the above formulas, everything cancels out and you find $g'(x) =0$.

---

Yes, it is somewhat silly to solve this particular problem this way. But hopefully, this will be of use to the author of the question if he wants to differentiate, say, $\log_x(1+x)$.