# Derivative of the power tower

Tags: analysis, derivatives

May somebody help me to correctly calculate the dervative of the $n$-th power tower function?

$$
\begin{align}
f_1(x)&=x\\
f_n(x)&=x^{f_{n-1}(x)}\\
&=x^{x^{x^{...^x}}}\text{ where }x\text{ occurs }n\text{ times}
\end{align}
$$

The solution given [here](http://www.quora.com/Why-does-a-derivative-for-the-infinite-power-tower-x-x-x-exist) is for the infinite case $f_{\infty}=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n$.

Comment: What is wrong with the solution found there? I did not find any step that did not make sense, but I may have overlooked something. Still, it would surprise me why a professor in Mathematics at Clark University should provide an incorrect analysis of the problem.

Comment: they say that y=x^ybut in fact if the power ups by n times it will be Y(n)=x^Y(n-1)

Comment: It is an infinite power up, that is a limit. You cannot use $n$ here.

Comment: The $\ldots$ implies that this is an infinite tower, which is what David Joyce computed the derivative of.

Comment: @RazvanParaschiv what is $1 - 0.999...$?

Comment: What is your concept of infinity, Razvan? What you say is true of any finite number of powers $n$, but not when infinity is involved, since $\infty-1=\infty$ if we are to make sense of such statement.

Comment: This is what i was told by maths teacher and im studying at the best high school here. He told me that when i take out an "x " there will remain n-1 powers.Dont know guys. i was just asking :D

Comment: If you are asking for the derivative of a finite power tower, that is something different @RazvanParaschiv. Is that actually, what you are after? Then the question should be rephrased to reflect that!

Comment: Probably i misunderstood the task.Can you help me with that problem? Thank you and sorry for my mistake!

Comment: @RazvanParaschiv: Is my last edit correctly reflecting your question?

Comment: yes ,indeed.Thank you for your help sir!

Comment: Something fun is to make a DL at 0 with this function ! :P

Comment: See this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1032089/166413

Comment: @RazvanParaschiv: Would you consider accepting one of the answers? Best regards, String.

Comment: thank you for the link! It is really useful and ,indeed, the answer which the owner has consider correct is in fact correct! thank you, sir for your help!

Answer (score 3):

My approach would be to try to find derivatives inductively. First we have $f_1'(x)=1$. Then differentiating $f_2(x)=x^{f_1(x)}$ we have
$$
\log(f_2(x))=f_1(x)\log x\implies\frac{f_2'(x)}{f_2(x)}=f_1'(x)\log x +\frac{f_1(x)}{x}=1+\log x
$$
so that $f_2'(x)=f_2(x)(1+\log x)=x^x(1+\log x)$ and more generally
$$
f_n'(x)=f_n(x)\cdot\left(f_{n-1}'(x)\log x+\frac{f_{n-1}(x)}{x}\right)
$$
Then perhaps looking at $f_3',f_4'$ some kind of pattern emerges that can be proven inductively. But perhaps someone comes up with something smarter.

---

The notation gets messy, so let us instead write $a_n:=f_n(x)$ and $b_n:=f_n'(x)$ together with $c:=\log x$ and $d:=1/x$ to have
$$
b_n=a_n(c\cdot b_{n-1}+d\cdot a_{n-1})\\
$$
so with this we get
$$
\begin{align}
b_2&=a_2(c\cdot b_1+d\cdot a_1)\\
b_3&=a_3(c\cdot b_2+d\cdot a_2)\\
&=a_3(c\cdot a_2(c\cdot b_1+d\cdot a_1)+d\cdot a_2)\\
&=c^2\cdot a_3a_2b_1+cd\cdot a_3a_2a_1+d\cdot a_3a_2\\
b_4&=a_4(c\cdot b_3+d\cdot a_3)\\
&=a_4(c\cdot(c^2\cdot a_3a_2b_1+cd\cdot a_3a_2a_1+d\cdot a_3a_2)+d\cdot a_3)\\
&=c^3\cdot a_4a_3a_2b_1+c^2d\cdot a_4a_3a_2a_1+cd\cdot a_4a_3a_2+d\cdot a_4a_3
\end{align}
$$
and maybe a pattern has emerged. It looks like we have, noting that $b_1=1$ and $d\cdot a_1=1$ and defining $a_0=1$:
$$
\begin{align}
b_n=&c^{n-1}d\cdot a_na_{n-1}\cdots a_2a_1a_0+c^{n-2}d\cdot a_n\cdots a_1\\
&+c^{n-3}d\cdot a_n\cdots a_2+...+d\cdot a_n a_{n-1}\\
=&\sum_{i=1}^n c^{n-i}d\cdot \prod_{j=i-1}^n a_j
\end{align}
$$

---

Let us try to prove this. The base cases $n=1,2,3,4$ have already been computed above. So let us turn to the inductive step:
$$
\begin{align}
b_{n+1}&=a_{n+1}(c\cdot b_n+d\cdot a_n)\\
&=a_{n+1}\left(c\cdot\left(\sum_{i=1}^n c^{n-i}d\cdot \prod_{j=i-1}^n a_j\right) +d\cdot a_n\right)\\
&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n c^{n+1-i}d\cdot \prod_{j=i-1}^{n+1} a_j\right)+d\cdot a_{n+1}a_n\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} c^{n+1-i}d\cdot \prod_{j=i-1}^{n+1} a_j
\end{align}
$$
which proves the claim.

---

Substituting back the values of $a_n,b_n,c$ and $d$ we then have shown that
$$
\begin{align}
f_n'(x)&=\sum_{i=1}^n (\log x)^{n-i}\frac 1x\cdot \prod_{j=i-1}^n f_j(x)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n (\log x)^{n-i}\cdot x^{-1+\prod_{j=i-1}^n f_{j-1}(x)}
\end{align}
$$
where $f_0(x)=1$ and $f_{-1}(x)=1$ have been added.

Comment: i have riched this point and he asked me"then ,who is f'(n-1).Can you provide a general form?"

Comment: These derivatives get more and more complicated.  So this method is not advisable to compute the derivative for $f_\infty$.

Comment: @GEdgar: But we are after $f_n'$ and not $f_\infty'$.

Comment: ... and each $f_n'$ is more complicated than the previous one.  You can do as many as you have patience for as shown here.  But do not hope for a general formula in terms of $n$.

Comment: i tried to calculate the last 4 terms with the hope that ill  find out a general form,but unluckily i got stucked.Might there be any documents with the result for this exercise?

Comment: And once again my answer get downvoted although I am more than willing to hear constructive feedback instead. Downvoting should be saved for those who show careless behaviour, not sincere posters, I think.

Comment: OK, the downvote disappeared. No harm done!

Comment: @GEdgar: I agree! I have not found anything appealing about those expressions yet in terms of some "nice" inductive pattern.

Comment: really good!Big up!

Comment: I was wondering why did you assume that a0 is equal to 1?

Comment: @RazvanParaschiv: To make complete the pattern. We had the first term in the examples $b_2,b_3,b_4$ to be of the form $$c^{n-1}\cdot a_n\cdot a_{n-1}\cdots a_2\cdot b_1$$ but I really wanted it to match the form of the other terms, namely getting rid of $b_1$, adding $d$ as a factor, and adding $a_1,a_0$ as factors. Then all terms follow the same pattern. Luckily $b_1=1$ could just be left out, and $d=1/x$ and $a_1=x$ made it possible to multiply by $d\cdot a_1$ without changing it. Then defining $a_0=1$ made it all fit.

Comment: i finally understood.You have defined a0 as 1 to make it legit.Thank you ,indeed!

Answer (score 2):

Write
$$
f_{-1}(x)=0;\qquad f_n(x) = x^{f_{n-1}(x)}
$$
so that $f_0(x)=1$ and the higher ones are the same as before.  Then
$$
\frac{d}{dx} f_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n
x^{\left(-1+\sum_{j=n-1-k}^{n-1}f_j(x)\right)}\log^{k-1}(x)
$$

Comment: your statement from the first part might be wrong as there cant be x^x^x... by ba negative number of times

Comment: @RazvanParaschiv: $f_{-1}(x)=0$ gives $f_0(x)=x^0=1$ and so $f_1(x)=x^1=x$ such that $f_2(x)=x^x$ and so on, so it works just fine.

Comment: Does $\log^{k-1}(x)$ mean $(\log x)^{k-1}$ rather than $\log\log\log...\log x$ in your formula. I suppose it does. Could you provide any details as to how you derived it?

Comment: Yes, $\log^{k-1}(x) = (\log x)^{k-1}$.  How did I do it?  I had Maple do the case $n=6$ and observed the pattern.  Given the formula, can you prove it by induction?

Comment: @GEdgar: I will have a look :o) Great work!

Comment: @GEdgar: I think I managed to do it. Would you mind to have a quick look?

Answer (score 2):

let ${}^nx$ = $x\uparrow\uparrow n =\underbrace {x^{x^{\cdot ^{\cdot ^{x}}}}}_{n}$  the nth tetration of x

> Our goal: Is to find $\displaystyle{d\over dx}(^nx)$

Calculating some derivatives at first to try understand the patterns:

$\displaystyle{d\over dx}(^2x) = x^x(1+\ln x)$

$\displaystyle{d\over dx}(^3x) = (^3x)(^2x)\Big({1\over x}+\ln x+(\ln x)^2\Big)$

$\displaystyle{d\over dx}(^4x) = (^4x)(^3x)\Big({1\over x}+{^2x\over x}\ln x+{}^2x(\ln x)^2+{}^2x(\ln x)^3\Big)$

Now, we begin to notice a pattern involving $\ln x$. Just computing one more expression

$\displaystyle{d\over dx}(^5x) = (^5x)(^4x)\Big({1\over x}+{^3x\over x}\ln x+{({}^3x)({}^2x)\over x}(\ln x)^2+({}^3x)({}^2x)(\ln x)^3+({}^3x)({}^2x)(\ln x)^4\Big)$

---

Computing the general derivative

Since $\displaystyle {}^nx = x^{\big({}^{(n-1)}x\big)} = e^{{}^{(n-1)}x\ln x}$

Therefore
$${d\over dx}({}^nx) = {d\over dx}(e^{{}^{(n-1)}x\ln x}) = e^{{}^{(n-1)}x\ln x}{d\over dx}\big({}^{(n-1)}x\ln x\big) = {}^nx\Big({{}^{(n-1)}x\over x}+\ln x {d\over dx}\big({}^{(n-1)}x\big)\Big)$$

Now try to cast the general form of the derivative to resemble the pattern in the calculated derivatives, you can see they come in the form: 
$${d\over dx}({}^nx) = ({}^nx)({}^{(n-1)}x)\Big({1\over x} + \cdots \Big)$$

Now, we could make 
$${d\over dx}({}^nx) = ({}^nx)({}^{(n-1)}x)\Big({1\over x} + {{d\over dx}\big({}^{(n-1)}x\big)\over {}^{(n-1)}x}\ln x\Big)$$

Notice that the derivative always starts with two tetration factors; so that
$${{d\over dx}\big({}^{(n-1)}x\big)\over {}^{(n-1)}x{}^{(n-2)}x} = B(n) = \text{The big bracket}$$

Now, we could rewrite the derivative as
$${d\over dx}({}^nx) = ({}^nx)({}^{(n-1)}x)\Big({1\over x} + {}^{(n-2)}x\ln x B(n-1)\Big)$$

$B(n)$: the big bracket can also be defined recursively as 
$$B(n) = {1\over x} + {}^{(n-2)}x\ln x B(n-1), \text{ if } n>3$$
$$B(3) = {1\over x} + \ln x + (\ln x)^2$$

---

$$\begin{align}{d\over dx}({}^nx)
&= ({}^nx)({}^{(n-1)}x)B(n) \\
&= ({}^nx)({}^{(n-1)}x)\Big({1\over x} + {}^{(n-2)}x\ln x B(n-1)\Big) \\
&= ({}^nx)({}^{(n-1)}x)\Bigg({1\over x} + {}^{(n-2)}x\ln x \Big({1\over x} + {}^{(n-3)}x\ln x B(n-2)\Big)\Bigg) \\
&= ({}^nx)({}^{(n-1)}x)\Bigg({1\over x} + {{}^{(n-2)}x\over x}\ln x + {}^{(n-2)}x{}^{(n-3)}x(\ln x)^2 B(n-2)\Big)\Bigg) \\
&= ({}^nx)({}^{(n-1)}x)\Bigg({1\over x} + {{}^{(n-2)}x\over x}\ln x + {}^{(n-2)}x{}^{(n-3)}x(\ln x)^2 \Big({1\over x} + {}^{(n-4)}x\ln x B(n-3)\Big)\Bigg) \\
&= ({}^nx)({}^{(n-1)}x)\Bigg({1\over x} + {{}^{(n-2)}x\over x}\ln x + {{}^{(n-2)}x{}^{(n-3)}x\over x}(\ln x)^2 + {}^{(n-2)}x{}^{(n-3)}x{}^{(n-4)}x(\ln x)^3 B(n-3)\Bigg) \\
&= ({}^nx)({}^{(n-1)}x)\Bigg({1\over x} + {{}^{(n-2)}x\over x}\ln x + {{}^{(n-2)}x{}^{(n-3)}x\over x}(\ln x)^2 + \cdots + \Big(\prod^i_{j=2}{{}^{n-j}x}\Big){(\ln x)^{i-1}\over x} + \cdots + \Big(\prod^{n-2}_{j=2}{{}^{n-j}x}\Big){(\ln x)^{(n-3)}}B(3)\Bigg) \\
&= ({}^nx)({}^{(n-1)}x)\Bigg({1\over x} + {{}^{(n-2)}x\over x}\ln x + {{}^{(n-2)}x{}^{(n-3)}x\over x}(\ln x)^2 + \cdots + \Big(\prod^i_{j=2}{{}^{n-j}x}\Big){(\ln x)^{i-1}\over x} + \cdots + \Big(\prod^{n-2}_{j=2}{{}^{n-j}x}\Big){(\ln x)^{(n-3)}} \Big({1\over x} + \ln x + (\ln x)^2\Big)  \Bigg) \\
\end{align}$$

Now, all terms in $B(n)$ follow the same general form: $\displaystyle\Big(\prod^i_{j=2}{{}^{n-j}x}\Big){(\ln x)^{i-1}\over x}$, where $i$ is the index of the term, except the last 3 terms but notice the following similarity:

**The third last term** equals $\displaystyle\Big(\prod^{n-2}_{j=2}{{}^{n-j}x}\Big){(\ln x)^{(n-3)}\over x}$ which is the same as its general formula

**The second last term** equals 
$$\Big(\prod^{n-2}_{j=2}{{}^{n-j}x}\Big){(\ln x)^{(n-3)}}\cdot \ln x = 
({}^1x)\Big(\prod^{n-2}_{j=2}{{}^{n-j}x}\Big){(\ln x)^{(n-2)}\over ({}^1x)} = 
\Big(\prod^{n-1}_{j=2}{{}^{n-j}x}\Big){(\ln x)^{(n-2)}\over x}$$
again it is the same as its general formula

**The last term** equals 
$$\Big(\prod^{n-2}_{j=2}{{}^{n-j}x}\Big){(\ln x)^{(n-3)}}\cdot (\ln x)^2 = 
({}^0x)({}^1x)\Big(\prod^{n-2}_{j=2}{{}^{n-j}x}\Big){(\ln x)^{(n-1)}\over ({}^0x)({}^1x)} = 
\Big(\prod^{n}_{j=2}{{}^{n-j}x}\Big){(\ln x)^{(n-1)}\over x}$$
again it is the same as its general formula

Note that $\displaystyle ({}^0x) = 1, ({}^1x) = x$

---

Now we deduce that

$$\begin{align}{d\over dx}({}^nx) &= ({}^nx)({}^{(n-1)}x)\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\Bigg[\Big(\prod^i_{j=2}{{}^{n-j}x}\Big){(\ln x)^{(i-1)}\over x}\Bigg]} \\
&= {({}^nx)({}^{(n-1)}x)\over x}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\Bigg[{(\ln x)^{(i-1)}}\prod^i_{j=2}{{}^{n-j}x}\Bigg]}\blacksquare
\end{align}$$