# Differentiating $x^{x^{x^{...}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

> How do I differentiate $$ x^{x^{x^{...}}}$$ with respect to $x$? (Note that $x$ is raised infinitely many times.)

My attempt: Let $y = x^{x^{x^{...}}}$. Taking logarithm of both sides we get $\ln y = y \ln x$ and let $f = y \ln x - \ln y$. Now $$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}} = \frac{y^2}{x(1 - y \ln x)}$$
Is this approach correct? If not how do I proceed ?

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should have a look to see if this map is well defined. Or a least to look at its domain.

Comment: Pauly covered the infinite tower problem in the **remark** of [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1032089/721644) starting with $\varphi_n(x)=\varphi_{n-1}(x)$.

Comment: Yes your answer is correct. Thought about sharing this, hope it helps: https://youtu.be/i_l1lz26C2M

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The infinite tetration $y=x^{x^{x^{...}}}$ corresponds to
$$y=-\frac{W(-\log (x))}{\log (x)}$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function. Use the chain rule knowing that
$$\frac d{dt} W(t)=\frac{W(t)}{t (W(t)+1)}$$

Answer (score 5):

The way I would do this:
$$y=x^{x^{x^{\cdots}}}=x^y=\exp(y\ln x)$$
where I've used the notation $\exp(...)$ instead of $e^{\cdots}$ to make the working neater. Now, differentiating implicitly with respect to $x$, and using the fact that $\frac{d}{dx}e^{f(x)}=f'(x)e^{f(x)}$gives
$$\begin{align}\frac{dy}{dx}&=\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\ln x+\frac{y}{x}\right)\exp(y\ln x)\\
&=\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\ln x+\frac{y}{x}\right)x^y\end{align}$$
Rearrange to isolate $\frac{dy}{dx}$:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\left(1-x^y\ln x\right)=\frac{yx^y}{x}\implies\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{yx^y}{x(1-x^y\ln x)}=\frac{y^2}{x(1-y\ln x)}$$

which is the same result that you got; your way seems fine :)

---

I hope that was useful. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask :)