# Extremum of $f(x) = x^{x^{x^{…{x^x}}}}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis, functions

How can I find extremum of $f(x) = x^{x^{…{x^x}}}$, where x is written 2n times? I tried looking at f’(x), but it didn’t get me anywhere. I also researched tetration (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration), but didn’t find anything on my problem. All ideas are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: LImit of $x^{x^{x^\ldots}}$ is known.

Comment: @Wuestenfux only for some values of $x$- for others there is no limit.

Comment: @Wuestenfux, how can it help with the extremum? If u look at the graph of, say, x^x^x^x, there’s also a local minimum somewhere between 0 and 1. I am trying to figure out where exactly. For x^x it’s at 1/e

Comment: I doubt there is an easy answer, though for $x^{x^{x^x}}$ it [appears to be](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=minimise+x%5E%28x%5E%28x%5Ex%29%29+) about $0.593237$ at when $x\approx0.274689$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534820/how-can-we-calculate-xx

Comment: @Nurator I have no problem differentiating f, I can’t find zeros of f’

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the logarithm trick for $x^{g(x)}$:

$f(x) = x^{g(x)} => \ln(f(x))= \ln(x) \cdot g(x)$

Thus, differentiating gives us

$\Rightarrow \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{g(x)}{x}+\ln(x)\cdot g'(x)$

$\Rightarrow f'(x)= g(x)x^{g(x)-1}+\ln(x)\cdot g'(x)$

As $g(x)$ is of order less than before, you can recursively use this formula to get to a direct formulation of $f(x)$.

Comment: I thought of that, too, but if we write down f’(x) we get a complicated equation on x and we can’t really find zeros of f’ for big n.

Answer (score -1):

Let $f(x)=y$. The given function can be put as $y=x^y$.
Or $\log y=y\log x$

Differentiating wrt $x$, we get

$\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}+\frac{dy}{dx} \log x$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{y}{x}}{\frac{1}{y}-\log x}$

Can you proceed from there, noting that for extremum, the derivative vanishes?

Comment: Doe this assume $n$ is infinite?

Comment: You had the same idea as me :D But dont you need to consider the inner derivative of y?

Comment: Still, the equation we get for n > 2 is rather complicated and I can’t get to the answer.